# What Pathfinder prestige classes have full spell-casting progression?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

When optimizing spell-casting characters in Pathfinder it is conventional wisdom one should not give up caster levels. What first-party prestige classes offer full spell-casting progression for divine or arcane spellcasters?

Comment: Is it the intent to limit this to first-party releases only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following classes offer full spell-casting progression for either arcane or divine spellcasters.

[Arcane Trickster](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/prestigeClasses/arcaneTrickster.html) (10 levels) - Requires 2d6 of sneak attack and ability to cast a 2nd level arcane spell. Increases sneak attack and applies it to spellcasting.

[Loremaster](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/prestigeClasses/loremaster.html) (10 levels)

[Mystic Theurge](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/prestigeClasses/mysticTheurge.html) (10 levels) -  Requires 2nd level arcane and divine spells. Increases spellcasting for both an arcane and divine class.

[Diabolist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/diabolist) (10 levels) - Imp companion

[Dissident of Dawn](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/dissident-of-dawn) (10 levels) - Requires ability to cast *daylight* as a divine spell. According to the [current FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qow) this can be satisfied by a spell-like ability.

[Envoy of Balance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/envoy-of-balance) (10 levels)

[Genie Binder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/genie-binder) (5 levels)

[Harrower](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/harrower) (10 levels)

[Hell Knight Signifer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/hellknight-signifer) (10 levels)

[Soul Warden](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/soul-warden) (10 levels) - Grants channel energy

[Spherewalker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/spherewalker) (5 levels)

[Veiled Illusionist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/veiled-illusionist) (10 levels) - Adds illusion spells from sorcerer/wizard spell list

The following classes offer almost full spell-casting progression for either arcane or divine  spellcasters. They give up no more than one level of spell casting progression.

[Agent of the Grave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/agent-of-the-grave) (5 levels) - Special abilities for summoned undead

[Arcane Savant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/arcane-savant) (7 levels) - Adds spells from any spell list

[Demonaic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/demoniac) (10 levels) - Demon lord boons

[Evangelist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/evangelist) (10 levels) - Gains all class features for 9 levels of her aligned class

---

#### Arcane

The following classes offer full spell-casting progression for arcane spellcasters.

[Bloatmage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/bloatmage) (10 levels) - Cast spells without using spell slots

[Collegiate Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/collegiate-arcanist) (10 levels) - Requires ability to prepared 3rd-level arcane spells. Adds druid and Good domain to spell list.

[Cyphermage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/cyphermage) (10 levels) - Special scroll abilities

[Mage of the Third Eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/i-m/mage-of-the-third-eye) (10 levels) - Requires arcane school class feature

[Natural Alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/n-r/natural-alchemist) (10 levels) - Grants alchemist discoveries and bombs

The following classes offer almost full spell-casting progression for arcane spellcasters. They give up no more than one level of spell casting progression.

[Eldritch Knight](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/prestigeClasses/eldritchKnight.html) (10 levels) - Requires martial weapon proficiency. Gives full BAB progression.

[Daivrat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/daivrat) (10 levels) - Get one spell from any spell list each day

[Technomancer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/technomancer) (10 levels)

[Winter Witch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/winter-witch) (10 levels) - Witch only

---

#### Divine

The following classes offer full spell-casting progression for divine spellcasters.

[Divine Scion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/divine-scion) (10 levels)

[Exalted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/exalted) (10 levels) - Gives Deific Obedience boons, domain spell-like abilities, and a mini *miracle*.

[Green Faith Acolyte](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/green-faith-acolyte) (10 levels) - Grants animal companion

[Inheritor's Crusader](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/i-m/inheritor-s-crusader) (3 levels) - Only Cleric or Paladin. Full BAB

The following classes offer almost full spell-casting progression for divine spellcasters. They give up no more than one level of spell casting progression.

[Balanced Scale of Abadar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/divine-assessor) (6 levels)

Comment: Assuming this is a valid question, which... I tend to think it is, you really don’t need to make this community wiki. You’ve done all this work to come up with the list, you deserve the credit/reputation.

Comment: @KRyan I made it community wiki so that others can easily edit it as Paizo publishes more splat books.

Comment: I think you meant bloodmage, not bloatmage :)

Comment: @SangoProductions Bloatmage is correct, but might be IP of some sort. Using Blood for magic tends to want you to have lots of it, which makes you, well... bloated.

Comment: Is this all of them?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's all of them published by Paizo that are included on [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes). It doesn't include any other publishers. It also doesn't include prestige classes that can be taken for a few levels giving up only one level of spellcasting, the most notable of which is the [dragon disciple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/dragon-disciple); the first four levels of it are a +strength prestige class by themselves.

Comment: A lot of those classes only grant partial, not full spellcasting progression.

Comment: @KRyan Is this thing really too broad? Why?